# SSRS Dataset keeps rerunning

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report that seems to take quite a while to run. When I run a SQL Server Profile Trace on the session to see what it is doing it just seems to be re-running the same stored procedure over and over and over - for hours!!

Is this something anyone else has experienced problems with? If so, where did you start to look in diagnosing the cause?

This is becoming a problem as it is a report that sits on a subscription schedule which seems to run all day (if the session is not picked out and killed) and then interferes with our Database Overnight jobs which then crash!

Any help anyone has on this would be great!

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Check for hidden datasets.

Comment: Edit the RDL file and search for your SP name to see if it's called only in the required place. Also check your shared datasources if any.

Comment: Are you using a sub report or a table nested inside another table?

Comment: Thanks All - No shared Dataset and having checked the raw RDL there is only one instance of the Stored Procedure that is continually being re-run. An Enigma!!??!!